Query Store Plan Forcing is Failing with OPTIMIZATION_REPLAY_FAILED
I am trying to use Query Store to force a particular plan in an Azure SQL DB database, and it's not obeying me! I've checked in sys.query_store_plan, and it has a column which describes the reason for the failure. Some of these are pretty straightforward  to understand (e.g. "NO_INDEX: Index specified in plan no longer exists"). However, the error message that I get is OPTIMIZATION_REPLAY_FAILED, which is described in the documentation as "The optimization replay script failed to execute."
I would like to figure out why the optimization replay script failed to execute, but I can't find anything out there that really says anything more detailed that what I've wrote above. How I can figure out what is stopping my plan from being forced?

good question, seems the default answer is computer says NO but hopefully someone here can shed a little more light.

I am unsure, but the extended event QueryStore_Plan_Force_Failure might give more information!

That's an excellent suggestion @SqlWorldWide that I hadn't thought of - thanks! Unfortunately that event isn't available for Azure SQL Database that I can see, but there are a few others that might be helpful. I've set that running and will see what is captured, if anything.

As you've already figured out, the Query Store force plan failures are stored in the sys.query_store_plan DMV
SELECT 
    qsp.plan_id
    , CAST(qsp.query_plan AS xml) AS QueryPlan
    , qsp.has_compile_replay_script
    , qsp.plan_forcing_type
    , qsp.plan_forcing_type_desc
    , qsp.last_force_failure_reason
    , qsp.last_force_failure_reason_desc
FROM sys.query_store_plan AS qsp
WHERE 
    qsp.last_force_failure_reason <> 0
    and qsp.has_compile_replay_script = 1

The OPTIMIZATION_REPLAY_FAILED error refers to the new functionality of SQL2022 called Optimized plan forcing.
I don't have a repro so I can't check, but the replay script should be stored in the plan XML (as per the documentation):

An optimization replay script is stored as part of the compressed showplan XML in Query Store, in a hidden OptimizationReplay attribute.

There are also two Extended Events to trace this failure:

query_store_failed_to_load_forced_plan - though I don't think it will give any more info than the DMV above
opt_replay_exception_info - which might be more promising but I have no idea what kind of data it shows.

It would be help if you could post both the script replay portion of the XML plan and the result from opt_replay_exception_info XE.
Please note that the second Xevent doesn't appear in the GUI by default. You first have to enable the Debug Channel like so:


Many thanks Zikato - this is really useful information. I've had a look for the OptimizationReplay attribute in the plan's XML and there's nothing with that name. Perhaps this is the problem in and of itself? It does mention that the attribute is hidden, so perhaps there is something I'm missing. I'll try to force another plan and see what the results of that are. I'll try adding opt_replay_exception_info to my XE (thanks for the debug tip) and report back with findings here. Unfortunately this thing only runs once per day and is quite a sensitive production issue, so I have to be careful!

So I've managed to capture something in the XE session, but I don't think there's anything useful in it: <RingBufferTarget truncated="0" processingTime="0" totalEventsProcessed="1" eventCount="1" droppedCount="0" memoryUsed="52">   <event name="opt_replay_exception_info" package="sqlserver" timestamp="2024-06-28T14:30:45.373Z">     <data name="opt_replay_error_state">       <type name="uint32" package="package0"></type>       <value>21</value>     </data>   </event> </RingBufferTarget>

In addition, OptimizationReplay doesn't appear anywhere in the plan XML. I am starting to think that this is the problem. I'm still working on successfully forcing a plan to see what is in the XML then. If my theory is right there will be some reference to OptimizationReplay in there

I have done a bit more work on this and had a look at all the execution plans for queries that have a compile replay script (compile_replay_script = 1 in the query above). None of them have any reference to the hidden OptimizationReplay attribute in the XML, so I can only guess that it is properly hidden in the sense that I can't see it, and it doesn't appear in the execution plan XML in a conventional way. There doesn't seem to be any more documentation on the OptimizationReplay attribute either, so I am now properly stuck!

Found this Data Exposed video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKLFgJgETsw which describes the query replay script, and in particular, at around 4:55 he says that you won't find the replay script in the execution plan XML. So I'm pretty much back to square one now. I know the replay script failed but I don't know why
